# BLE background scanner with Xamarin.Forms (iOS)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to scan Bluetooth devices in the background when screen is locked with Xamarin.Forms for iOS.

**Setup:**

- [Bluetooth LE plugin for Xamarin & MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet-bluetooth-le/dotnet-bluetooth-le) to perform the scan.
- Xamarin.Forms DependencyService to invoke native platform functionality from shared code (Start/Stop scanner).
- Info.plist with Enabled Background Modes
- Test devices: iPhone 8 (iOS 15.6.1) and iPad Air 3 (iOS 15.1).

**Issues:**

- When screen is locked scanner stops scanning.
- After some time (about 30 seconds) the background process stops working and kills the application.
- Guid filter does not work.

**Info.plist**

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>

    <array>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>external-accessory</string>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>
    <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your message</string>
```

**BLE_Scanner_iOS**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Scan_BLE_test.iOS;
using Plugin.BLE;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UIKit;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BLE_Scanner_iOS))]

namespace Scan_BLE_test.iOS
{
    public class BLE_Scanner_iOS : IStartStopScan
    {

        private static object syncObj = new object(); // thread safe lock()

        /* LOG data */
        private static int current_rssi = 0;
        private static string selected_device_name = "";

        IAdapter Adapter;
        IBluetoothLE Ble;
        bool runningFlag;

        public void Start_Ble_Scan()
        {
            runningFlag = true;// set runningFlag to true

            Ble = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
            Adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {

                nint taskId = 0;
                //expirationHandler only called if background time allowed exceeded
                taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exhausted time");
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
                });
                while (runningFlag == true)
                {

                    lock (syncObj)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Running loop...");
                        Console.WriteLine(UIApplication.SharedApplication.BackgroundTimeRemaining);

                        Scan_BLE(10000);

                        Console.WriteLine($"Device {selected_device_name} rssi {current_rssi}");// debug log

                    }
                    await Task.Delay(1000);

                }
                ////Only called if loop terminated due to myFlag and not expiration of time
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskId);
            });
        }


        async void Scan_BLE(int scan_time_i)
        {
            // Check if Device Bluetooth is on
            if (Ble.State == BluetoothState.On)
            {
                // Check if Adapter is already scanning 
                if (!Adapter.IsScanning)
                {
                    Adapter.ScanTimeout = scan_time_i;
                    Adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.Balanced; // Set scan mode as Balanced
                    //Scan and search for devices
                    Adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
                    {
                        if (a.Device.Name != null)
                        {
                            lock (syncObj)
                            {
                                current_rssi = a.Device.Rssi;
                                selected_device_name = a.Device.Name;
                            }

                        }
                    };
                    var scanFilterOptions = new ScanFilterOptions();

                    // does not work 
                    //scanFilterOptions.ServiceUuids = new[] {
                    //    Guid.Parse("F640A514-908B-CCAF-E5EB-89AE701CF346")

                    //}; // cross platform filter


                    await Adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync(scanFilterOptions); // scan for pre defined scane time 
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[INFO] Scanned"); // Debug scanned

                }
                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[WARNING] device is scaning");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[WARNING] BLE State is OFF ");
            }
        }


        public void Stop_Ble_Scan()
        {
            runningFlag = false;// set runningFlag to false
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

The last beacon read with its rssi is shown on the screen and the application is about to be closed by the system.

```
[0:] [WARNING] device is scaning
2022-11-16 12:49:49.063 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[46180:1980782] Running loop...
2022-11-16 12:49:49.064 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[46180:1980782] 26,5684510833526
2022-11-16 12:49:49.066 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[46180:1980782] Device Beacon1 rssi -85
2022-11-16 12:49:50.091 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[46180:1980781] Running loop...
[0:] [WARNING] device is scaning
2022-11-16 12:49:50.092 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[46180:1980781] 25,540871916688
2022-11-16 12:49:50.094 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[46180:1980781] Device Beacon1 rssi -85
[0:] [WARNING] device is scaning
2022-11-16 12:49:51.134 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[46180:1980781] Running loop...
2022-11-16 12:49:51.135 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[46180:1980781] 24,4981506250042
2022-11-16 12:49:51.136 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[46180:1980781] Device Beacon1 rssi -85
```

Comment: Isn't that expected to happen if you lock the phone?

Comment: Have you done any research on background tasks in iOS?  The available options and their limitations are well documented